# Best practice for adding property to Web API output

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have quite an extensive Web API application that several different systems use to gather data. I have been asked to add a property to the result of each method for the time taken for the method to execute. I can do this using OnActionExecuting/OnActionExecuted in an action filter, but I need to work out the best way of returning the time without breaking what I have already.

For more complex objects, I can have the class be extended from a base class which contains the TimeTaken property:

```
public class ApiBaseModel {
    public int TimeTaken {get;set;}
}

public class ApiModel : ApiBaseModel {
    // other properties
}

// in Web API controller
[ApiTimeTakenFilter]
[HttpGet]
public ApiModel GetApiModel() {
    return new ApiModel();
}


// in filter
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);

    actionContext.Request.Properties[StopwatchKey] = Stopwatch.StartNew();
}

public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
{
    base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);

    Stopwatch stopwatch = (Stopwatch)actionExecutedContext.Request.Properties[StopwatchKey];

    long delay = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    var objectContent = actionExecutedContext.Response.Content as ObjectContent;
    if (objectContent != null)
    {
        var value = objectContent.Value; //holding the returned value

        if (value is ApiBaseModel)
        {
            // put the delay into the object
            ((ApiBaseModel)value).TimeTaken = delay;
        }

    }
}
```

That should be fine in not breaking the API for previous versions, but I have lots of methods that return simple objects, eg

```
[ApiTimeTakenFilter]
[HttpGet]
public bool IsOK {
    return true;
}
```

So, if I change this to a complex return type, I'll break the integrity of the API for existing users.

Is there some other mechanism I can use for passing the TimeTaken value for all methods, without breaking the API?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered writing it to the Http Response Header from your filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add it to the Http Response header like so. Then you will not break any existing code and interested clients can retrieve it.

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
{
    base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);

    Stopwatch stopwatch = (Stopwatch)actionExecutedContext.Request.Properties[StopwatchKey];

    long delay = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.Add("requestTime", delay.ToString());
}
```

You can also register the filter globally in the WebApiConfig.cs file.

Comment: Simple and non-breaking.  Nice.

Comment: Thanks very much, this is exactly what I was after! Yes, the filter is registered globally, I just wanted to demonstrate in the sample code that it was being applied.